# Building a .deb of a Python project fails - dpkg-buildpackage is trying to delete files as directories?

Tags: python, debian, ubuntu-12.04, deb, dpkg

This is my second attempt to create a deb file - the first was a C project which I used FPM for - this worked perfectly, albeit an unacceptable package - it works.  This one, however, is a Python project (GNS3), and I'd prefer to do it properly, since if I'm going to do it - it may as well be right.  Having said that, right now I'd settle for a .deb file that worked.

The problem: I've been modifying GNS3 as a project, and the final step I need to do is to re-package it into a .deb file.  I know it can be done, since its in the Ubuntu repos, but my research led me to the information that someone called Erik Wenzel at Debian built the deb and he was no longer available - and the developers of GNS3 apparently have a focus on Windows and don't have current knowledge to package it ("allegedly" - I've asked them recently but have not yet heard back - if I do I'll add any info they provide to this question).

I've tried various different ways to get a debian package, but the last one I tried seemed the most promising.  I used (from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb):

```
python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb
```

which gave me the tarball, then tried:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -us
```

which didn't work.  It fails with this output (snipped from the end):

```
...
dh_python2 -O--buildsystem=python_distutils
dh_usrlocal -O--buildsystem=python_distutils
dh_usrlocal: debian/python-gns3/usr/local/share/examples/gns3/baseconfig.txt is not a directory
dh_usrlocal: debian/python-gns3/usr/local/share/examples/gns3/baseconfig_sw.txt is not a directory
rmdir: failed to remove `debian/python-gns3/usr/local/share/examples/gns3': Directory not empty
dh_usrlocal: rmdir debian/python-gns3/usr/local/share/examples/gns3 returned exit code 1
make: *** [binary] Error 25
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

The errors are correct(?!) - those two files are not directories - they are text files - and they don't appear to have any unusual characteristics:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 steved swdept 4096 Feb 27 16:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 steved swdept 4096 Feb 27 16:57 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 steved swdept 3146 Feb 26 15:00 baseconfig_sw.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 steved swdept 257 Feb 26 15:00 baseconfig.txt
```

It appears that STDEB is doing its part properly - but I can't say for sure.  It might be doing something that is causing dpkg-buildpackage to fail.  What I'm hoping is that someone will look at this and go, "Of course that won't work - you need to do x and y, then it will build".  Or at least a, "Try this and this".

If I can get this right then I'll also be able to contribute the knowledge back to the GNS3 project, which would be great.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Just put this in your debian/rules file `override_dh_usrlocal:` and this will stop dh_usrlocal from running which i think is actually causing you problems. I was stuck with similar situation and doing this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Do not install anything in `/usr/local`. And if you want to package a new version of software that already has an official package don't try to make a pakcage from scratch, modify the existing one instead.

Comment: I haven't changed the install path from the original source, but I believe there was some talk about moving its installation location on the GNS3 forums.  As to modifying the original package, is there a correct way to do that?  I'm not making a new version as such, its more of a fork.

Comment: @Steve use `dch --local` to add a new changelog entry and make any modifications you need.

Comment: I might be doing this wrong, but I've used AR to unpack the deb, used python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb to create a new archive to replace data.tar.gz and then repackaged it with AR, but it no longer appears to be a deb file to dpkg.  I haven't had a chance to look at it in-depth yet, but am I on the right track?  Cheers

Comment: @Steve On the totally wrong one. Start with http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/